# Проверка принадлежности точки фигуре, заданной двумя функциями

Tags: c#

Дано задание:Дана точка на плоскости с координатами (х, у). Составить программу, которая выдает одно из сообщений «Да», «Нет», «На границе» в зависимости от того, лежит ли точка внутри заштрихованной области, вне заштрихованной области или на ее границе.

И в общем-то оно не трудное, если бы мне не была дана функция, с которой я понятия не имею как работать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня даже есть готовое решение, но для другого варианта

```
using System;
namespace Hello
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("x=");
            float x = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("y=");
            float y = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (x * x + y * y < 9 && y > 0)
                Console.WriteLine("внутри");
            else if (x * x + y * y > 9 || y < 0)
                Console.WriteLine("вне");
            else Console.WriteLine("на границе");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение практически идентично вашему примеру.

```cs
if (y > 0 && y < 12 && Math.Abs(x) < y)
    Console.WriteLine("внутри");
else if ((y >= 0 && y <= 12 && Math.Abs(x) == y) || (y == 12 && Math.Abs(x) < y))
    Console.WriteLine("на границе");
else
    Console.WriteLine("вне");
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Я не знал как разобраться с математической стороной этой задачи

Comment: спс, я тут не часто просто